rustc_span::source_map::SourceMap::lookup_source_file gives false local path
I'm studying the code of rupta, a pointer analysis framework for rust. I tried to add some codes to rupta, in order to learn where certain function is defined, given the DefId of that function, as follows:
let cur_tcx: rustc_middle::ty::context::tyCtxt = /* snipped */;
let def_id_of_func: rustc_span::def_id::DefId = /* snipped */;

let cur_session: rustc_session::session::Session = /* snipped */;
let source_map = cur_session.source_map();
let span = cur_tcx.def_span(def_id_of_func);
let file = source_map.lookup_source_file(span.lo());

With the variable file, I wrote these codes in addition, trying to figure out the exact path that the file locates in the file system:
let filename = file.name.clone();
let filename_cloned = filename.clone();
let path_of_file = match filename {
    FileName::Real(real_file_name) => match real_file_name {
        RealFileName::LocalPath(path_buf) => Ok(path_buf),
        RealFileName::Remapped {
            local_path: path_buf_optional,
            virtual_name: virtual_path_buf,
        } => {
            if let Some(path_buf) = path_buf_optional {
                Ok(path_buf)
            } else {
                Err(format!("Virtual: {}", virtual_path_buf.to_string_lossy()))
            }
        }
    },
    _ => Err(format!("Other: {:?}", filename_cloned)),
};

It works just fine in most cases, however something weird happened. For example, when analyzing config.rs from the rustc_session crate, the codes above indicate that the file is located in /home/<my-user-name>/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-2024-02-03-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/compiler/rustc_session/src/config.rs. However the actual path is /home/<my-user-name>/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-2024-02-03-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/rustc-src/rust/compiler/rustc_session/src/config.rs instead.
This phenomenon also happens when rupta analyzes rustc_driver_impl, rustc_errors and rustc_error_messages, which are all from rustc-dev.
In short, I want to figure out two questions:

Why does rustc_span::source_map::SourceMap::lookup_source_file gives non-existent file paths?
Did I do wrong when fetching the file path that certain function is defined in? If so, is there any other way to do the same task?

Sadly I have little experience developing inside rustc. Being not familiar with the rustc_* libraries, I really don't have any idea what I should try next.
All I am expecting is that I could know the real file path of the functions in the crates mentioned above. I am alse curious about the reason that rustc_span::source_map::SourceMap::lookup_source_file gives false file paths.

You might find that the #t-compiler/help stream on Rust's Zulip chat may be a better forum for this question, as it is monitored by the compiler team/experts (some of whom participate here too, but this question is quite niche for StackOverflow).

However, as you've already asked here, if you get an answer there please post it here too (as a self-answer).

I see, thanks for your advice, I'll try to ask them for help then.
